# RMI Naming.lookup throws NotBoundException

Tags: java, rmi

I have some objects registered in my Rmi registry, i check that it's done because when i do a LocateRegistry.getRegistry().list() it results 2 registries like:

```
0 = "rmi://Mac.local/192.168.1.40:1099/DataService"
1 = "rmi://Mac.local/192.168.1.40:1099/AuthService"
```

Then, i call a

```
ServicioAutenticacionInterface authService = (ServicioAutenticacionInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://Mac.local/192.168.1.40:1099/AuthService");
```

It throws a NotBoundException..

Just say that interfaces are in a package named commons defined as a dependency for server package who is it´s trying to invoke that lookup.

Comment: How are you binding the objects to the registry ?

Answer (score 0):

You passed a URL to `Registry.bind()/rebind()` instead of just a name.

- URLs are passed to `Naming.bind()/rebind()/unbind()/lookup()`, and returned by Naming.list()`.
- Simple names (such as `"AuthService"`) are passed to `Registry.bind()/rebind()/unbind()/lookup()`
- *Whatever* you passed to `Registry.bind()/rebind()` is returned *verbatim* by `Registry.list()`.

*Ergo,* as `Registry.list()` is returning URLs, you must have supplied them via `Registry.bind()/rebind()`.

For proof, try `Naming.list("rmi://Mac.local/192.168.1.40:1099")`. It will return this:

```
0 = "rmi://Mac.local/192.168.1.40:1099/rmi://Mac.local/192.168.1.40:1099/DataService"
1 = "rmi://Mac.local/192.168.1.40:1099/rmi://Mac.local/192.168.1.40:1099/AuthService"
```

which is obviously not what you want.

So you need to either use `Naming.bind()/rebind()` with the same URL strings, or else remove the URL part of the strings and keep using `Registry.bind()/rebind()`.

Comment: You 'get null as a result' **OF WHAT**?

Comment: As a result of Naming.lookup("DataService") and also for LocateRegistry.getRegistry().lookup("DataService");

Comment: Well (a) that isn't true: you got an exception, not a null; and (b) where have I told you to use the simple name in `Naming.lookup()`? Please reread what I actually wrote.

Answer (score 0):

**java.rmi.NotBoundException:**

My RMI-based application was working fine until I introduced another function which utilizes a service(WatchService), the service had an internal ***infinite loop*** and so this would stall the whole application.

My thought was that, when the server was started, maybe binding process did not completely happen because of the loop implemented inside the service, and the service was started at the same time during binding phase, and so when the client came looking up for the server stub, it could not find it because it wasn't bound or registered/fully in the first place.

When I removed the function/service everything worked fine again, but since I needed the service/function, I had to start it on a **new thread** inside the same class of the server *stub* like so

```
   private class FileWatcherThread implements Runnable {
        public FileWatcherThread() {
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
          startMonitors();
        }
    }
```

Then somewhere inside your main code start the defined thread above.

```
new Thread(new FileWatcherThread()).start();
```

And this ***startMonitors();*** is the method that has infinite loop and is defined in the main class, ***FileWatcherThread*** is an *inner* class of the main server class- it actually depends on how you have done your implementation and design. Just get the idea then see if it suits your problem.